# Field name converted to lowercase while pushing an object to firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

[image]

[image]
Im working on a Server Side version of my food app, so I've to make changes to my current existing data. But while pushing a model object to my firebase database the case of the fields "Image" and "Name" are automatically change to lower case, which become problematic while accessing these values using .child("Image") function. Can any body give me a workaroud?

```
public class CategoryModel {
    private String Image;
    private String Name;

    public CategoryModel(String image, String name) {
        Image = image;
        Name = name;
    }

    public CategoryModel() {
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return Image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        Image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the standard behavior for JavaBean type objects that are being serialized.  It's best to accept it, since it's the normally expected behavior.  (Note that your object fields are actually counter to the standard Java convention of starting with lowercase character.  But you are free to do whatever you want, eh?)

If you don't accept the default standard behavior, you can change the name of the field of each property being serialized by annotating the getter method with the [@PropertyName](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/PropertyName) annotation, which can change the field name used to seralize and deserialize the data.

```
@PropertyName("Image")
public String getImage() {
    return Image;
}
```

Again, I don't recommend this, but if you must...

Comment: yeah its a must, because I cant change the previous database which already has the fields starting with caps....thanks a lot frnd..:)